# How to subset a dataset using multiple exclusions?

Tags: r

How to combine all state names in a single vector, instead of listing all the logical exclusions separately? I found function %notin% on the CRAN website, but R doesn't recognize is as a legitimate function.

```
indata <- indata[which(indata$STATE != "GU" & indata$STATE != "WY" &
                       indata$STATE != "KS" & indata$STATE != "ME" &
                       indata$STATE != "MT" & indata$STATE != "ND" &), ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
indata[!indata$STATE %in% c("GU", "WY", "KS", "ME", "MT", "ND"), ]
```

EDIT: @CarlWitthoft, believe it or not, I've actually had the following in a private package for a while

```
`%notin%` <- function (x, table) x[!x %in% table]
```

However, I never think to use it until after I've already typed it out the long way.  Plus, using it makes my code less distributable.  I was not aware of

```
operators:::`%!in%`
```

which is only the second half of `%notin%`

Comment: Also take note of GSee's answer which does not require `which` as the indexing uses the TRUE/FALSE rather than numeric indexing that which creates (less typing and faster)

Comment: And for homework,  define an operator %notin% which performs that operation :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try again:

```
library(operators) 

x%!in%y  

#works fine
```